# Magic Square question

Tags: magic-square

Not sure whether this question is correct or not! Please help.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The squares already filled in don't even meet that criteria.

Comment: Yes, this is from one of the competitive Exam paper

Comment: Presumably the question refers to unfilled in rows, columns and diagonals in which case it is not a magic square

Comment: The question is flawed then. Even if we were to assume they meant $7$ instead of $3$, that would mean that the top right corner would have to be $0$, but then that diagonal would only equal $3$, not $7$. There's no solution.

Comment: Maybe, it is meant modulo $4$, but in this case, the exercise is made up badly.

Comment: modulo 4 seems to work, but only the answers must be expressed modulo 4

Answer (score 0):

If the upper left number was $-2$ instead of $2$, then the answer would be

\begin{array}{|r|r|r|}
\hline
   \color{red}{-2} &             5  &             0 \\
\hline
    \color{red}{3} & \color{red}{1} &            -1 \\
\hline
    \color{red}{2} &            -3  & \color{red}{4} \\
\hline
\end{array}